# How to adjust font size in two agreement plots in a knitr document - library(vcd)?

Tags: r, plot, font-size, knitr

I've created two agreement plots with the `vcd` package as part of a `knitr` document.  Each agreement plot is built on a 4x4 table comparing results from a test at the beginning of the year with results for a test at the end of the year.  Each plot describes a class and I am presenting the results of both classes for comparison.  The plots are generating and in the correct position though the approach might not be very elegant:

```
\begin{figure}[htpb]
<<agree1, fig.width=3, fig.height=2.5, out.width='.49\\linewidth', fig.show='hold',     echo=FALSE>>=
par(mar=c(.4,.4,.3,.3))

agreementplot(Class1, ylab = "First Test", xlab="Second Test", main="Math Groups Class 1")
agreementplot(Class2, ylab = "First Test", xlab="Second Test", main="Math Groups Class 2")
@
\end{figure}
```

The problem I am trying to solve is the font size for the axis labels - it is too large and needs to be reduced.

I have been unsuccessful with:

```
par(ps=8) 
fontsize=8
```

I'm wondering if one of those is the correct approach and I put it in the wrong place or if the solution is something else entirely.

I have searched on agreement plot font size and vcd font size but wasn't able to recognize a solution.

Any help or a pointer in a direction would be appreciated.
Cheers,
Chris

Comment: Found the solution, once I stopped thinking about font size and focused in on the margin settings and figure size, I was able to find a combination that worked for the labels and titles:  fig.width and fig.height=6 with par(mar=c(4,2,3,4) did the trick.

Comment: You are welcome to answer your own question below :)

Comment: vcd is based on grid graphics I believe, so par() would have no effect

Answer (score 0):

Here are the settings I finally settled on once I stopped thinking about font size and thought it through margin and figure sizes:

```
<<agree1, fig.width=7, fig.height=6, out.width='.6\\linewidth', fig.show='hold', echo=FALSE>>=
par(mar=c(5,2,3,4))
```